# Demand for touch support

Tags: discussion

For interactive questions, how much demand is there to be able to use a purely touchscreen device (no mouse, no physical keyboard). I'm asking thinking of Stack Snippets in questions. Are there any other places where being touch-enabled would make a difference?

I'm assuming tick boxes, radio buttons and selection boxes can all be used with a touchscreen device already. For the [question I'm planning](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5435/20283) the display will zoom when hovered over with the mouse pointer, and I'm wondering whether this is sufficient or whether touching the screen should also zoom in on that point. Without this I'm guessing the question will not be usable on a phone or tablet.

How many of you would want to be able to view such a challenge running on a screen-only device?

Answer (score 19):

## Don't trouble yourself

While I use my phone, and to a lesser extent my tablet, to browse around (and get notifications for) SE, I wouldn't be interested in running a full challenge in a snippet on my phone.

Most people who frequent the site are, by implication, people who read and/or write code. I have to assume there isn't a large percentage of them that don't have regular access to a keyboard/mouse.

While I wouldn't care if someone *did* add touch controls, it's not worth the effort in my opinion.

Comment: This is the answer I was hoping for - I'll be directing any complaints I receive this way :)

Comment: Umm.... thanks? You might consider giving it a while longer to collect dissenting answers first ;)